# Is DISTINCT applied before or after GROUP BY in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

Below is the query I'm running.  Does the `DISTINCT` get applied before or after the `GROUP BY`?

The table looks like this: `id, state`

The `id` is not unique, and an entity can have many entries with the same state or different states.

This behavior could drastically change my results.  If `DISTINCT` is applied before `GROUP BY`, then it will only count each `entity` once throughout the entire set ( will only show up in one `state` ).  If it happens after, then each `entity` will only be counted once per `state`, but could be counted in many `states`.

```
SELECT
    state,
    COUNT( DISTINCT entity_id ) AS count
FROM entities
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

My goal is to count each entity only once per `state` but to allow an `entity` to be counted in more than one `states` ... which is the behavior I would expect if `DISTINCT` is applied after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The same row in a database will never be counted more than once. Even if the GROUP BY runs first, that row will never be placed into multiple groups - only one. Do you have multiple rows with the same ID and a different value for `state`?

Comment: I have multiple rows with the same entity and a different state.  I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` is applied first:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92876/1

Using the same query as you've got in your question on the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE Entities (
  state INT,
  id INT
);

INSERT INTO Entities VALUES
  (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (2, 3);
```

the following result was output:

```
STATE | COUNT
1     | 3
2     | 2
3     | 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP BY` happens first. To do grouping, the database may look for a suitable index on state. That will result in something like this:

```
Stat ID
---- --
Iowa 1
Iowa 1
Utah 2
Utah 1
Utah 2
```

After grouping is done, `distinct` happens.

```
Iowa 1
Utah 2
Utah 1
```

And then follows count.

```
Iowa count-distinct = 1
Utah count-distinct = 2
```

Then `ORDER BY count DESC` kicks in.

```
Utah 2
Iowa 1
```

Comment: Descending is actually the other way around.